# How to return the nth last element in a singly linked list using recursion?

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list

So I have this recursive solution to **print** the nth element from the end of the list:

```
void print_nth_from_last_rec(Node* node, int n) {

    static int count { 0 };

    if (!node) return;

    print_nth_from_last_rec(node->next, n);

    if (++count == n)
        cout << node->data;

}
```

But I can't figure out how to **return** that element using recursion. Is it possible?

Attempts:

- I can do it if I have a static `Node*`  that will be assigned to when `(++count == n)`:

  ```
  Node* get_nth_from_last_rec(Node* node, int n) {

      static int count { 0 };
      static Node* ret{ nullptr };

      if (node) {

          get_nth_from_last_rec(node->next, n);

          if (++count == n)
              ret = node;
      }

      return ret;
  }
  ```
- It is also possible to pass in a reference to the `out` Node and assign the nth element to it.

But is there a better way? These statics don't look very clean to me.

Comment: You did not specify what type of list you are speaking about: whether it is a doble-linked list or a single-linked list.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: read the title

Comment: @ J.F. Sebastian, it is my mistake.:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Node* get_nth_from_last_rec(Node* node, int& n)
{
    if (node)
    {
        Node* result = get_nth_from_last_rec(node->next, n);
        if (result)
            return result;
        else if (! n--)
            return node;
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Note: it seems `n` is zero-based in your code i.e., the last non-null item in the list is considered to be `0`-th item. Usually the last item is `-1` (mod size).

Comment: I think the OP uses a 1-based `n`, i.e. `n--` should maybe become `--n` to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I'd do it (I hope it's obvious from context what `advance` does):

```
Node* get_nth_from_last(Node* node, int n, Node *ahead = 0) {
    if (ahead == 0) {
        // might like to check for size < n at the same time
        // and return something to indicate error in that case
        ahead = advance(node, n);
    }
    if (ahead->next == 0) return node; // or whatever the end condition is
    return get_nth_from_last(node->next, n, ahead->next);
}
```

If you want to hide that default parameter away from the caller, then use a helper function. It's only needed for efficiency anyway, if you want really slow code then do without it and call `advance` at every recursive step.

You should pretty much never need `static` variables just to make your recursion work. You can always add parameters with default values, or else write a helper function with extra parameters and call that to do all the work. Aside from any confusion they might cause the reader, they make the function non-thread-safe, and non-reentrant from signal handlers.

My code does `2 * len - n` node advances, and yours only does `len` (plus `n` pieces of work coming back out of the recursion). If you want to stick with your performance characteristics but sacrifice tail recursion, then something like this (I'm either out-by-one on this, or on my first answer, depending on the meaning of `n`...):

```
Node* get_nth_from_last_helper(Node* node, int &depth) {
    if (node == 0) return 0;
    Node *n = get_nth_from_last_helper(node->next, depth);
    --depth;
    return (depth == 0) ? node : n;
}

Node *get_nth_from_last(Node *node, int n) {
    return get_nth_from_last_helper(Node *node, n);
}
```

Comment: One benefit of the `static` variables is that they reduce the stack space needed (i.e. they increase the maximum recursion depth); however, you can achieve the same effect much more nicely by just passing a single pointer to a `struct` which keeps track of the state.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: this is tail-recursive anyway. So if stack use is a problem and the compiler can't solve it then there's a far more obvious fix, which is to <s>get a decent compiler</s> make the trivial transformation to an equivalent non-recursive function. But yes, you might use `static` variables as an optimization as you describe. I still say not just to make the recursion work, though.

Comment: Totally agreed. It just happened that when I read the question my eyebrows went north when I saw that `static` variables were used to transport state (this actually never occurred to me) and while thinking about it I realized that in *some* way it may seem plausible.

Comment: it seems `n` is zero-based in your code i.e., the last non-null item in the list is considered to be `0`-th item. Usually the last item is `-1` (mod size) i.e., `n` is 1-based. You could try `ahead = advance(node, n-1);`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: yes, I was just worrying about the same thing for my second version. As you say it should be easy enough to tweak based on the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use the nth from front function count down to 0

```
Node* get_nth_from_first_rec(Node* node, int n) {
    if (!node || n == 0) {
        return node;
    }

    return get_nth_from_last_rec(node->next, n - 1);
}
```

And count the number of elements in the list (recursively if you want)

```
int get_list_length(Node* node) {
    if (!node)  {
        return 0;            
    }

    return 1 + get_list_length(node->next);
}
```

So then I could compute the index as an nth from first index

```
Node* get_nth_from_last_rec(Node* node, int n) {
    int count = get_list_length(node);
    return get_nth_from_first_rec(node, n - count);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this get you the `n`'th element from the *front* instead of from the back?

Comment: Oh true. Yes it would. You would have to modify n to be length - n somehow. I was confused by the example.

Comment: You don't really need to know the length of the list - the OP's code is specifically written so that it starts counting when returning from the recursive step, i.e. it starts counting from the back.

Comment: It's the same thing. Counting to the end first is equivalent to starting from the back.

Comment: Right - I first thought that your solution is less efficient, but now I realize it depends on the values of `n`, i.e. if it is larger than the list length / 2 (i.e. the node to be returned is in the first half) your solution is actually scales better. If `n` is usually somewhere near the end, the OP's scales better.

Comment: Also don't forget about the memory footprint. See, the accepted answer pushes on the stack at each call. Each call pushes a value from the linked list onto the call stack. When we pop that stack in order, we get the reverse of the linked list. It is effectively creating the reverse list using recursion. If we did that iteratively you might say that pushing the items onto a stack was cheating. The example I have shown can be optimized for tail recursion, so we can avoid the stack limit and creating the reverse of the link list by abusing a stack.

Answer (score 0):

Here I believe I have a neat tail recursion way of solving it in Java.

```
public static LinkedListNode findnthToLastRecursionHelper(LinkedListNode node, LinkedListNode last,int pos){
    if(node==null) return null;
    if(pos<1)
    {
        pos=1; //We have reached the nth iteration for last, now time to increment node and last together.
        node = node.next;
        if(last==null) return node;
    }
    else if(last==null) return null;
    return findnthToLastRecursionHelper(node,last.next,--pos);
}
```

This is the main tail recursion chunk that cares of moving the `last` pointer to the `nth` position, and once position is reached it moves `node` & `last` pointer together.

```
public static LinkedListNode findnthToLastRecursion(LinkedListNode head,int pos){         
    return findnthToLastRecursionHelper(head,head.next,pos);
}
```

This is the caller function in order to maintain the aesthetics.